# meaning of the word assumed used in sentence

Tags: meaning

> The application of the rational model to the house-building process in the 1950s and ’60s led to suburban communities consisting of nearly identical structures. Indeed, it was possible to wander into the residence of someone else and not to realize immediately that one was not at home. The more expensive developments were superficially more diversified, but their interior layouts **assumed** residents who were indistinguishable in their requirements.

For the last sentence, what definition is being used for the word assumed?

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts are things, not people. Hence, layouts are incapable of assuming anything.

The architects and draftspeople who prepared hard-copies of the layouts, however, were informed by both custom and training to *assume* things about the people who would inhabit the structures they designed.

Put differently, the architects and designers assumed--wrongly of course, that every occupant of the houses they designed couldn't care less about how their houses were laid out.

The writer of the paragraph you cited made an assumption, too. He or she assumed that the architects and designers were filled with hubris in thinking their designs were simply great, as is. The writer seems also to assume that many people *do* in fact care a great deal about how their homes are laid out, and the tradespeople who do not realize this are falling down on their jobs.